# RecyclerView with pagination in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Helo, I create a recyclerview with complex items (its CardView with nested RecyclerView with grid layout manager). And I have problem with lags durring scroll. To fix that, I try to put main recyclerView in NestedScrollView, and add scroll listener(when NestedScrollView scrolled to end of content) for pagination. When I scroll first page, it works perfect, but, when new page was loaded, NestedScrollView change own height with freeze. And its look likes some catastrophe. Maybe you faced with some problem?

My recyclerView Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/news_item_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardElevation="3dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_item_avatar_img"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_item_avatar_img"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/news_item_more_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_full_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Кот черный"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/news_item_full_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_item_avatar_img"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/news_item_more_img"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_date"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_more_img"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_gray_18dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:id="@+id/news_item_content_txt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/news_item_image_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_like_count_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_14dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_item_like_count_img"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_middle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_like_count_txt"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_item_like_count_txt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_comment_count_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_black_14dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_item_comment_count_img"
            android:text="0"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_middle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_comment_count_txt"/>

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/news_item_label_txt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_label_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_label_black_14dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/news_item_label_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_middle"
            android:text="@string/group_str"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsItemHolder holder, final int position) {
    final PostEntity postEntity = newsList.get(position);

    holder.fullName.setText(userFullName);
    holder.date.setText(postEntity.getCreateAt());

    holder.content.setText(text);

    holder.likeCount.setText(String.valueOf(postEntity.getLikesList().size()));
    holder.commentsCount.setText(String.valueOf(postEntity.getCommentsList().size()));

    if(postEntity.getUserAvatar() != null) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(postEntity.getUserAvatar().getThumb())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.avatar);
    }

    if(postEntity.getPhotosList() != null && postEntity.getPhotosList().size() > 0) {
        holder.imageContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int cardWidth = width - dpToPx(16);

        ArrayList<PhotoEntity> shortListOfPhoto = new ArrayList<>();
        if(postEntity.getPhotosList().size() > 5){
            shortListOfPhoto.addAll(postEntity.getPhotosList().subList(0, 5));
        } else {
            shortListOfPhoto.addAll(postEntity.getPhotosList());
        }

        final GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(context,shortListOfPhoto, postEntity.getPhotosList(), cardWidth);

        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 4);
        holder.imageContainer.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return ClubUtils.getSpanLookup(galleryAdapter.getItemCount(), position);
            }
        });

        galleryAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);

        holder.imageContainer.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        holder.imageContainer.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
        holder.imageContainer.setHasFixedSize(true);


    } else {
        holder.imageContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: *And I have problem with lags durring scroll.*. To fix it why do you think you need a nestedscrollview. Also posting some relevant code will help

Comment: update question

Comment: @АлександрШевчук Have you figure out the solution ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Finally I used recyclerView without NestedScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Here scroll is NestedScrollView

```
      scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
                View view = (View) scroll.getChildAt(scroll.getChildCount() - 1);

                Log.d("CategoryNeswList", scroll.getChildCount() + " child");
                int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scroll.getHeight() + scroll
                        .getScrollY()));

                if (diff == 0) {
//                        getPlaylistFromServer("more");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Load More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do pagination like this.

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            if (dy > 0) {
                                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                                if (loading) {
                                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                                        if (totalItemCount != TOTAL_JOBS) {
                                            loading = false;
                                            Log.e("total", "ite" + totalItemCount + " count" + TOTAL_JOBS);
                                            PAGE_COUNT = PAGE_COUNT + 10;
                                            serviceCall();
                                        } else {
                                            loading = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

in this code TOTAL_JOBS : total no of jobs coming from server,
totalItemCount : is the total items in recyclerView ,
set  loading = true everytime if there is still response coming for recycleView;

Comment: if I use NestedScrollView scroll of recyclerView is disabled. I didn`t have problem with make pagination in Recycler. I had problem is to change nestedScrollView height without freezes when new data loaded, and recycler view chanched its height

Comment: use pagination from  NestedScrollView by using setOnScrollChangeListener

Comment: I already use setOnScrollChangeListener. "I had problem is to change nestedScrollView height without freezes when new data loaded"

Comment: put a loader over there and dismiss it after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Dude, you didn`t understand the problem.